# What is the "reactive" way to read file line-by-line

Tags: node.js, reactive-programming, rxjs

I'm learning reactive programming using RxJS and encounter a case when I need to read a file line-by-line. Actually I solved it using a solution likes:

https://gist.github.com/yvele/447555b1c5060952a279

It works, but I need to use some normal JS code to transform the stream of Buffers to stream of lines. (use "readline" module in example above)

I wonder if there are other ways to transform an Observable of Buffer to Observable of line, using RxJS operators, likes example below.

```
var Rx = require('rx');
var fs = require('fs');
var lines = Rx.Observable
  .fromEvent(rl, 'data') // emits buffers overtime
  // some transforms ...
  .subscribe(
    (line) => console.log(line), // emit string line by line
    err => console.log("Error: %s", err),
    () => console.log("Completed")
  );
```

Comment: what do you consider normal js code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably achieve something pretty close to what you want with `scan` and `concatMap`.

Something like:

```js
bufferSource
  .concat(Rx.Observable.of("\n")) // parens was missing // to make sure we don't miss the last line!
  .scan(({ buffer }, b) => {
    const splitted = buffer.concat(b).split("\n");
    const rest = splitted.pop();
    return { buffer: rest, items: splitted };
  }, { buffer: "", items: [] })
  // Each item here is a pair { buffer: string, items: string[] }
  // such that buffer contains the remaining input text that has no newline
  // and items contains the lines that have been produced by the last buffer
  .concatMap(({ items }) => items)
  // we flatten this into a sequence of items (strings)
  .subscribe(
    item => console.log(item),
    err => console.log(err),
    () => console.log("Done with this buffer source"),
  );
```

Comment: Extractly what I want. Seem like I miss the scan operator. Thank you.

Comment: I just noticed something, does your code not emit the last line?

Comment: Oh, if the last line is not terminated by "\n", indeed it will get lost! Let me try to fix it. EDIT: Fixed it on line 2 I think.

Answer (score 2):

I tried a bunch of the above answers and built my own ugly version. Then, I poked around the code on GitHub and found that RxJS handles stream like objects - there's no point in mucking around with events. Just pass a ReadStream to `from` and it tests it for `ReadableStreamLike` and then turns it into an `AsyncGenerator`.

```
import * as readline from 'node:readline';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

const file = fs.createReadStream(fileName);
const line = readline.createInterface({ input: file });

const line$ = from(line).subscribe({
  next:  (dat) => { ... },
  error: (err) => { ... },
  complete: () => { ... }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following class

```js
'use strict'

const lineReader = require('line-reader');
const Rx = require('rxjs');
const RxOp = require('rxjs/operators');

class CSVReader {
    constructor(filepath {
        this.filepath = filepath;
    }

    readByLines() 
    {
        const source = new Rx.Subject();

        lineReader.open(this.filepath, (err, reader)=> {
            Rx.of(0).pipe(
                RxOp.expand(val => {
                    reader.nextLine((err2, line) => source.next(line));
                    return Rx.of(1 + val);
                }),
                RxOp.takeWhile(_=> { 
                    let has = reader.hasNextLine();
                    if(!has) source.complete();
                    return has;
                })
            ).subscribe(_=>_);
        })

        return source;        
    }
}

module.exports = CSVReader
```

and use it as follows

```js
const { bufferCount } = require('rxjs/operators');

let reader = new CSVReader('path/to/file');

reader.readByLines()
    .pipe(bufferCount(2)) // chunk size
    .subscribe(chunk=> {
        console.log({chunk});
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would say like this:

```js
const readline = require('readline');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const {fromEvent, race, Observable} = require('rxjs');
const {tap, takeUntil, take, map} = require('rxjs/operators');



const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: fs.createReadStream(path.resolve('./', 'myfile'))
});


let obs = new Observable(observer=>{
    rl.on('line', val => observer.next(val)),
    rl.on('error', err => observer.error(err)),
    rl.on('close', complete => observer.complete(complete))
})
.pipe(tap(line=>console.log(`line: ${line}`)))

obs.subscribe(()=>{},
   (e)=>console.log(`Error reading file: ${e}`),
   ()=>console.log("Read complete"))
```

An alternative for creating the observable could be:

```js
let obs = fromEvent(rl, 'line')
.pipe(
    takeUntil(race(
        fromEvent(rl, 'close').pipe(take(1))  , 
        fromEvent(rl, 'error').pipe(map((err)=>{throw err}))   
    )))
```

Ideally, `rxjs` could have provided an operator like: `fromEvent(emitter, nextEvent, errorEvent, completeEvent )` to help keep the above code even simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this for a while and used TypeScript to solve some of the weird issues I was getting, so I hope you can work with this solution. Let me know if you'd prefer a vanilla JavaScript implementation :)

So, assuming you are trying to read from a csv file, the following method is the cleanest implementation that I have found to return and observable with the data parsed into objects after reading each line.

You can use this method to work with your data before you call `lines.push(row);` or you can call `readTabFile()` and work with the stream from there.

In this example I used a tab sepperated file, but you can also use this approach for csv files. It uses [csv-parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csv-parse) to map data onto the right interface.

```
import * as fs from 'fs';
import { parse } from 'csv-parse';
import type { Parser } from 'csv-parse';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

interface Columns {
  columnA: string;
  columnB: string;
}

function readTabFile(): Observable<Columns[]> {
  const parser: Parser = parse({
    delimiter: '\t',
    columns: ['columnA', 'columnB'],
  });
  return new Observable((observer) => {
    const lines: Columns[] = [];
    const stream = fs.createReadStream('./file.TAB', {
      encoding: 'utf8',
    });

    parser.on('data', (row: Columns) => {
      lines.push(row);
    });

    parser.on('end', () => {
      observer.next(lines);
      observer.complete();
    });

    stream.pipe(parser);
  });
}
```